# Unable to load SDK manager in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I tried to install Android Studio, I encounter the following problem

[image]

I have already installed HAXM from Intel and enabled VT-X but this prblem still exist. Android Studio does not even show SDK Manager.

I have tried

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio.
- Set the JAVA_PATH from environment variable
- Install HAXM from Intel
- Enable VT-X

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Add **C:\Windows\System32** to your **PATH** environment variable. To do this you should open Control Panel, go to **System -> Environment Variables**, find **PATH** in System Variables and add the following entry at the beginning: **%SystemRoot%\system32;**

Answer (score 0):

Well guys...finally I think I found the way out...
I had to reboot the system...install JDK...set the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE...enable VT-X technology and then install Android Studio...
I am still working on my project to let you it finally worked or not...but I'm kind of happy the installation was a success without error msgs